# How do I fix an invalid content-type header in Twilio using node.js?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, twilio, content-type

I've been working on the [Twilio projects from Radical Skills](https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/sms-respond/2.html), and I've been having trouble responding to incoming text messages using JavaScript. I'm able to use TwiML, which is XML, but I am unable to respond in JavaScript like the example shows.

My message request URL in Twilio is /incoming/handle-incoming-text.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Redirect method="GET">incoming/sms.js</Redirect>
</Response>
```

When my Twilio application receives a text message, it redirects to sms.js. I've copied this code directly from the [example](https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/sms-respond/2.html#sms-reply-reply-2).

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

if( req.Body == 'hello'){
    resp.message('Hi!');
}else if( req.Body == 'bye'){
    resp.message('Goodbye');
}
console.log(resp.toString());
```

When I send a text message saying "hello" from my phone to my Twilio number, I get the following responses.

```
GET /incoming/handle-incoming-text.xml 200 1ms - 240b
GET /incoming/sms.js 200 39ms - 251b
```

However, I do not get a text back from my Twilio number saying "Hi!" In fact, I do not get a response at all.

When I checked the error logs, it gave me a [12300 Invalid Content-Type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/12300) error with the following message.

> Twilio attempted to retrieve content from the URL  but was unable to process the application/javascript Content-Type header in the response. Please see the Twilio XML Markup Documentation for more details on valid Content-Type settings.

One of the headers in my response is "Content-Type application/javascript." According to the [twilio-node helper library documentation](http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/#twimlResponse), it should output XML. However, it does not appear to be working properly.

I've spent several hours trying to figure this out, and I still haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It seems that the Radical Skills project is missing some detail. I'd suggest you take a read through [this blog post on the node.js helper](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html) written by my colleague Kevin. It takes you through how to set up a web server to properly respond to Twilio. For this particular issue, you can take a look at [the section on handling SMS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html#crayon-54dc76cc33824487668685).

Hope this helps, let me know if I can help more.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That link helped point me in the right direction to get my app working properly.

I also found [this Twilio blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/09/send-daily-sms-reminders-using-firebase-node-js-and-twilio.html) helpful.